# /bin/bash: ./darknet: No such file or directory error in Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, darknet

I am trying to train custom data. I run this script:

```
!./darknet/ detector train data/obj.data cfg/custom-yolov4-detector.cfg yolov4.conv.137 -dont_show -map.
```

It was working fine but recently I'm getting /bin/bash: ./darknet: No such file or directory error.

Note: I am in the content/darknet folder. I don't understand the problem.